# Abstract class and operator!= in c++

Tags: c++

I have problem implementing the operator!= in a set class deriving from an abstact one. The code looks like this:

```
class Abstract
{
  public:
     //to make the syntax easier let's use a raw pointer
     virtual bool operator!=(const Abstract* other) = 0;
};

class Implementation
{
    SomeObject impl_; //that already implement the operator!=
  public:
    bool operator!=(const Abstract* other)
    {
      return dynamic_cast<Implementation*>(other)->impl_ != this->impl_;
    }
};
```

This code works but it has the drawback to use dynamic_cast and I need to handle error in casting operation.

This is a generic problem that occur when a function of a concrete class it is trying to using some internal information (not available at the abstract class level) to perform a task.

Is there any better way to solve this kind of problem?

Cheers

Comment: You say this works?  Are you sure?  I could be mistaken, but I believe if you try to run it you will only see the comparison of the != operator on the pointers (that is, your overridden operator will never get called) because you'd be comparing an `Abstract*` to another `Abstract*` (the left hand side of `operator!=` as a member function would be `Abstract&` which cannot exist since the class has a pure-virtual function).

Comment: You should take the arguments by reference instead of taking pointers. This will be confusing, as you will have to dereference the left hand side but not the right hand side when dealing with to pointers: `Abstract *p1, *p2; /* work with them */ if (*p1 != p2 ) {}` the `if` is confusing: how could an object and a pointer not be different?

Comment: @Zac Howland: Not really, since it is a method, the left hand side argument must be an object, not a pointer. This is different from trying to define `bool operator!=( Abstract*, Abstract* );` which you cannot. Also, the fact that a class is abstract does not mean that you cannot have references to it: `Implementation i; Abstract &r = i;` is perfectly valid code. What you cannot have is an `Abstract` instance, but references are fine.

Comment: This code cannot work since `Implementation` doesn't derive from `Abstract`. `dynamic_cast` only works for polymorphic types, which is not the case.

Comment: Is there only one implementation of this interface?  If so, make the interface constructor private and use friend to allow access to the implementation, that way you can use `static_cast` and be guaranteed it will succeed.

Comment: sorry I have forgot " : public Abstract". But I hope my intentention was clear.

Comment: @David:  I assumed the OP wanted to do a comparison of like types.  If he wants to compare a referenced object to a pointer in this manner, the answer is simply "don't do it!" since it will make the code very confusing (as you pointed out already).  What I meant by the reference cannot exist is simply that when overriding `operator!=` as part of the interface, the implicit first argument is `this`, thus comparing `pA != pB` would be comparing the pointer values (as `pA` would be an `Abstract*` and not `Abstract&`).

Comment: If you must implement comparison operators in a base class, use the *virtual operator* idiom:  operator calls a virtual method that the descendants must implement.  See my answer below for a nice *gotcha*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't want to implement equality operators, `==` or `!=`, in a base class.  The base class has no idea how many or the content of the descendants.

For example, using the `Shape` class example:

```
struct Shape
{
  virtual bool equal_to(const Shape& s) const = 0;  // Makes Shape an abstract base class.
  bool operator==(const Shape& s) const
  {
     return equal_to(s);
  }
  bool operator!=(const Shape& s) const
  {
     return !equal_to(s);
  }
};

struct Square : public Shape
{
  bool equal_to(const Shape& s) const;
};

struct Circle : public Shape
{
  bool equal_to(const Shape& s) const;
};

struct Flower : public Shape
{
  bool equal_to(const Shape& s) const;
};

struct Cloud : public Shape
{
  bool equal_to(const Shape& s) const;
};
```

In order to satisfy the equality operators of the Shape class, each descendant must implement the `equal_to` method.  *But wait, how does `Square` know what type the other `Shape` is?*

In this example, the `Square` class would need to use `dynamic_cast` on the reference to cast to a `Square` object.  This will fail when the argument is a `Circle`, `Flower`, `Cloud` or some other yet to be defined shape.

The following is a valid concept that you have to watch out for:

```
Square my_square;
Cloud  my_cloud;
Shape * p_shape_1 = &my_square;  // Square is-a Shape, so this is legal.
Shape * p_shape_2 = &my_cloud;   // Cloud inherits from Shape, so this is legal.

if (*p_shape_1 == *p_shape_2)  // Legal syntax because of Shape::operator==().
{ //???}
```

The comparison above invokes **nasty** behavior.  This could come about in generic functions that operate only on shapes.

### Resolution

**Change the Design**.  You should never put a public comparison operator, that compares to a base class, in the base class.  Nasty.

**Descendents compare to Descendants. Period.**  Squares to Squares, Flowers to Flowers and Circles to Circles.  Implement comparison operators in descendant classes.

**Compare Base Class Content:**  If you have shared content in the base class, implement a protected method to compare the base class methods only:

```
struct Shape
{
  protected:
    bool equal_shape_content(const Shape& s) const;
};
```

This will make your program more robust because it compares only the Shape's content with another Shape.  This is about all that you can guarantee.  See also *Base Class Slicing*.

Comment: If you need to compare abstract shapes for equality or inequalty, perhaps your design is flawed.  This is a descendant of the type check rule:  if your checking types, there probably is a flaw in your design (except for *factory* patterns).

Answer (score 2):

Or if that isn't possible (eg because SomeObject isn't known when the Abstact class is defined) you'll have to fully handle it..

```
class Abstract
{
  public:
     //to make the syntax easier let's use a raw pointer
     virtual bool operator!=(const Abstract* other) = 0;
};

class Implementation : public Abstract
{
    SomeObject impl_; //that already implement the operator!=
  public:
    bool operator!=(const Abstract* other)
    {
      // remember that dynamic cast can't remove a 'const' qualifier
      const Implementation* o = dynamic_cast<const Implementation*>(other);
      return (o == NULL || o->impl_ != this->impl_);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

What you have in your question will not work.  Writing a simple test application below produces the same output on every compiler I have available to me at the moment (MSVC, GCC):

```
class Abstract
{
public:
    virtual bool operator!=(const Abstract* rhs) = 0;
};

class Implementation : public Abstract
{
public:
    virtual bool operator!=(const Abstract* rhs)
    {
        std::cout << "Implementation::operator!= called" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Abstract* pA = new Implementation;
    Abstract* pB = new Implementation;
    if (pA != pB)
    {
        std::cout << "Compared the pointers" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Compared the pointers
```

You cannot overload operator!= to compare 2 pointers in this manner.  You can do the following:

```
bool operator!=(const Abstract* lhs, const Abstract* rhs)
{
    return lhs->SomeVirtualFunctionThatReturnsUsefulInformation() != rhs->SomeVirtualFunctionThatReturnsUsefulInformation()
}
```

But I HIGHLY recommend against it since it makes comparing your pointers (the actual value of the pointers) impossible.

Instead, you would be better off using this approach:

```
class Abstract
{
public:
    virtual bool Equals(const Abstract* rhs) = 0;
};

class Implementation : public Abstract
{
public:
    bool operator==(const Implementation& rhs)
    {
        return this->SomeFunctionThatReturnsUsefulInformation() == rhs.SomeFunctionThatReturnsUsefulInformation();
    }

    virtual bool Equals(const Abstract* rhs)
    {
        Implementation* pRHS = dynamic_cast<Implementation*>(rhs);
        if (!pRHS) // not an Implementation of Abstract
        {
      return false;
        }
  return *this == *pRHS;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Abstract* pA = new Implementation;
    Abstract* pB = new Implementation;
    if (pA->Equals(pB))
    {
        std::cout << "Works" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about adding a virtual implementation getter to the Abstract class so that you can simply say

```
return other->GetImp() != GetImp();
```

Comment: This is the type of replay that I was looking for. The solution is generic. I am sorry that my error reporting the example focus the attention to the other people on the mechanical problem of my example code. Thanks

Comment: If two implementations have different types of implementation (eg: `Implementation` uses `SomeObject`, while `OtherImplementation` uses `SomeOtherObject`) this solution won't work. Also this cannot work if `operator!=` for two differente implementations can be different. Come on, why would you need a **virtual** `operator!=` if any `operator!=` does the same and any implementation class has the same implementation object?

Comment: Sorry, I was to quick to reply. @Peoro: Your are right, I have just realized that ;-)

Answer (score 1):

There are many things wrong with the example you provided, but in general, you could use a non-virtual overload, avoiding the cast:

```
class Implementation 
{     
  SomeObject impl_; //that already implement the operator!=   
public:     
  virtual bool NotEqual(const Abstract* other)     
  {       
    Implementation *pImplementation=dynamic_cast<Implementation*>(other);

    return !pImplementation || 
           other->impl_ != this->impl_;     
  } 

  bool NotEqual(const Implementation* other)     
  {       
    return other->impl_ != this->impl_;     
  } 
};
```

Now, if you have an `Implementation *` at the call site, the overloaded function will get called and no cast is necessary.

Comment: +1, This is a step forward, but still you need to check the result of the `dynamic_cast<>` before dereferencing to make sure that it is not null. Still, splitting into two functions is the way to go.

Comment: You said "avoiding the cast" but `dynamic_cast` is still there.  Did you post the wrong code?

Comment: @Ben, the cast is avoided by calling the overloaded version with a derived class pointer.

Comment: @Michael: How is the library consumer going to get a pointer to the internal implementation class?

Comment: @Ben, I understood this as a general question, not one in which the Implementation type is hidden, because it's in some library. In that case, the cast is necessary, at least for this example.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: This does clearly not remove the need for the cast, but it is better than the original code as internal code to the library can perform comparisons without upcasting (implicit) to the base and then downcasting (`dynamic_cast<>`) to the derived type --which incurs in some extra cost also.

Answer (score 0):

You can either implement a virtual getter on the abstract level:

```
class Abstract
{
  public:
     //to make the syntax easier let's use a raw pointer
     virtual bool operator!=(const Abstract* other) = 0;

  private:
     virtual SomeObject& getImpl() = 0;
};

class Implementation : public Abstract
{
    SomeObject impl_; //that already implement the operator!=
  public:
    bool operator!=(const Abstract* other)
    {
      return other->getImpl() != this->getImpl();
    }

  private:
    SomeObject& getImpl()
    {
      return impl_;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the most practical alternative is just to check the types before comparing:

```
bool operator!=( const Abstract * other )
{
    if( other == NULL || typeid( *other ) != typeid( Implementation ) )
        return true;

    return static_cast<Implementation *>( other )->_impl != _impl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When trying to do something that involves two or more polymorphic objects, a virtual method on one and `dynamic_cast` on the other is usually your best option.  There are other approaches, but they are necessarily complicated.

I would also give the virtual method a different name than the operator.  Reduces confusion at least for me.

```
class Abstract
{
public:
    virtual ~Abstract();
    virtual bool equal_to(const Abstract&) const = 0;
};
inline bool operator==(const Abstract& x, const Abstract& y)
{
    return x.equal_to(y);
}
inline bool operator!=(const Abstract& x, const Abstract& y)
{
    return !(x==y);
}

class Implementation { /*...*/ };

bool Implementation::equal_to(const Abstract& obj) const
{
    const Implementation* der_obj = dynamic_cast<const Implementation*>(&obj);
    if (!der_obj) return false;
    return impl_ == der_obj->impl_;
}
```

Be sure to check whether the result of `dynamic_cast` is NULL.  Presumably there could be multiple implementation classes (if not now, in the future).

Also my above `Implementation::equal_to` may or may not be correct if there are any subclasses of `Implementation`.

Answer (score 0):

To implement your `operator!=` you need some sort of double dispatch: that's it, you need to call a function depending on the type of both objects.

To avoid the issue you talked about (always using `dynamic_cast`), just overload `operator!=` so that it takes an `Implementation` object.

---

The solution I usually choose is similar to the one you proposed.

Any derived class' `operator!=` checks if the type of the `Abstract` object is the same of the implementation type, if it is cast the `Abstract` object as `Implementation` and run your checks.

I'd suggest using `type_info`+`static_cast` instead of `dynamic_cast`, since the latter is slower.

---

Other ways to implement double dispatching in C++ are available, like using the Visitor Pattern (or many others), but I wouldn't suggest it in this case, since they're more annoying to be implemented and give other advantages you don't need.

---

A couple of notes:

- You should pass references, why would you define a comparison operator between an `Abstract` object and a pointer?
- That code is not working at all. For example in your snippet `Implementation` doesn't inherit from `Abstract`, thus you cannot use `dynamic_cast`.

Comment: What about class derived from `Implementation`?  Only `dynamic_cast` will work right.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: technically you're right about it, but from a logical point of view I don't agree. Can an object of type `A` be equal to an object of type `B` (with `B` inheriting `A`)? In my code I usually give a different semantics to the equality operator: `a==b if and only if type(a)==type(b) and a.members==b.members`, but it of course depends on the semantics you want to give to your equality operator.

Comment: That's a reasonable argument, but it's a very different argument from "`dynamic_cast` is slower".

Comment: @Ben Voigt: right. I took for granted that also the OP could want something like this, but shouldn't have.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done without dynamic_cast, and can work even properly but uses the "evil" of the base-class knowing all its sub-classes. (A typical problem too with the Visitor pattern) using double-dispatch.

You may be able to get around with having an external class that knows all the implementations rather than having it in the actual base class.

With the simple model I will have Abstract and Impl1 and Impl2. I will call the method equals()

```
class Abstract
{
 public:
   virtual ~Abstract() {}
   virtual bool equals( const Abstract * other ) const =0;
   virtual bool equals_Impl1( const Impl1 * other ) const { return false; }
   virtual bool equals_Impl2( const Impl2 * other ) const { return false; }
};




class Impl1 : public Abstract
{
 public:
    bool equals( const Abstract * other ) const
    {
        return other->equals_Impl1( this );
    }
    bool equals_Impl1( const Impl1 * other ) const
    {
       // calculate and return true if they compare
    }
};

 // do the same with Impl2
```

Not ideal as it is not "extensible", i.e. you cannot add Impl3 without modifying Abstract to support it.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to implement abstract operator!=, I believe the most elegant is using template. You must define **template<class T> class Abstract**. Than in concrete class extends **public Abstract<Implementation>**.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<class T>
class Abstract {
public:
    virtual bool operator!=(const T & other) = 0;
};

class Implementation : public Abstract<Implementation> {
    int value;
public:
    Implementation (int param) { value = param; }
    bool operator!=(const Implementation & other) {
       return value != other.value;
    }
};

int main () {
    Implementation n1 (10);
    Implementation n2 (20);
    if (n1 != n2) {
        cout << "n1 != n2\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Other way, much more generic is implement a Comparable interface:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<class T>
class Comparable {
public:
    // pure virtual compare
    virtual int compare (const T & other) const = 0;

    // not equal operator
    bool operator!= (const T & other) const {
        return compare (other) != 0;
    }

    // other operators: == < > <= >=
};

class Number : public Comparable<Number> {
    int value;
public:
    Number (int param) { value = param; }
    virtual int compare (const Number & other) const {
        if (value < other.value) return -1;
        if (value > other.value) return 1;
        return 0;
    }
};

int main () {
    Number n1 (10);
    Number n2 (20);
    if (n1 != n2) {
        cout << "n1 != n2\n";
    } 
}
```